# How to write a function to create a vector x of length l, swap x[1:1/L] elements with x[1+1/L:L]

Tags: r

I have to create a vector x of length l that swaps the x[1:1/l] elements with
the x[1+1/l:l]. If the length of the vector is odd the middle element is unchanged.

Output should be c(A,B,C,D,E,F) to c(D,E,F,A,B,C) if the length of the vector is even.
If the length of the vector is odd, for c(A,B,C,D,E) it should be c(D,E,C,A,B).

Any hints to do this?

Comment: I gather that you want to swap the second half with the first half, but the notations `x[1:1/l]` and `x[1+1/l:l]` don't represent the halves, as far as I can tell. It would probably help others help you to describe the problem in valid R notation. Or just omit notation altogether and just say you want to swap the halves and give an example, that works too.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps.

```
f <- \(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  n2 <- n/2
  if (n %in% 0:1) x
  else if (n %% 2 != 0) {
    fl <- floor(n2)
    cl <- ceiling(n2)
    c(x[(cl + 1):n], x[cl], x[1:fl])
  } else {
    c(x[(n2 + 1):n], x[1:n2])
  }
}


f(LETTERS[1:6])
# [1] "D" "E" "F" "A" "B" "C"

f(LETTERS[1:5])
# [1] "D" "E" "C" "A" "B"
```